# Backbonejs only fetching one record on PHP JOIN

Tags: php, join, backbone.js, fetch

Alright, so I have a php that responds to a GET HTTP request; this php script calls the database, and retrieves a set of rows.

```
$results = $db->pdoquery("SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id ORDER BY posts.cre DESC LIMIT 4");
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
```

Now when I use backbonejs '.fetch' command, it only returns 1 the first record, as opposed to the four.

If I change the php script I get all four, but I have to lose my JOIN

```
$results = $db->pdoquery("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY posts.cre DESC LIMIT 4");
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE :
The JSON that the php page prints

```
[{"id":"7","post_name":"title","pretty_url":"link1","preface":"a preface 7","body_text":"a body","feat":"0","img":"\/img\/logo.png","cre":"2012-07-22","modi":"2012-07-18","user_id":"2"},{"id":"6","post_name":"title","pretty_url":"link","preface":"a preface 6","body_text":"a body1","feat":"0","img":"\/img\/logo.png","cre":"2012-07-21","modi":"2012-07-18","user_id":"2"},{"id":"5","post_name":"TestTitle 1","pretty_url":"testlink4","preface":"a preface 5","body_text":"a body 2","feat":"0","img":"\/img\/logo.png","cre":"2012-07-20","modi":"2012-07-16","user_id":"2"},{"id":"4","post_name":"TestTitle 1","pretty_url":"testlink3","preface":"a preface 4","body_text":"a body 3","feat":"0","img":"\/img\/logo.png","cre":"2012-07-19","modi":"2012-07-16","user_id":"2"}]
```

Comment: What does happen if you execute this query directly over your DB `SELECT * FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id ORDER BY posts.cre DESC LIMIT 4`?

Comment: The query returns all 4 rows. The PHP page prints out a json array with all four as well.

Comment: Can you show us the resulted `json`? (update your question)

Comment: Why does your JSON contain strange things like `"0":"7"` and `"1":"title"`? Does `$results` act like both a normal array and an associative array? Is there any way to get just the key/value pairs out of `$results` and ignore the numeric indexes? Then `json_encode` just the key/value pairs and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, results was a combination of numeric and assoc array because I was using PDO, I changed the JSON so it is only assoc now. Still didn't fix the problem though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Posts and Users has columns with identical names, mainly 'id', and since these four post records has the same user_id, the 'id' column was then set the same value.

Backbone must have something built in that skips over what it considers to be identical records or something of the sort. Simply describing what I needed in more detail fixed the issue.

Regardless the code that fixed it is below

```
        $results = $db->pdoquery("SELECT 
        posts.post_name, posts.pretty_url, posts.preface, posts.img, posts.cre, posts.modi, users.username
        FROM posts 
            JOIN users 
                ON posts.user_id=users.id 
                ORDER BY posts.cre 
                DESC LIMIT 4");
    $json = json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
```

Thanks to everyone that helped though.